# Change URL from controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, url-parameters

Is there a way to change the current url params from the controller so when the page is loaded, additional/different parameters are displayed in the address bar?

Here's what I mean, say I have an action 'Products':

```
public ActionResult Product(int productId)
{
  ..
}
```

I mapped the routes so that `product/4545/purple-sunglasses` is mapped to the function above, the product name is actually ignored, but I want, that if the product name is not specified, the controller should add this, so the product gets in easily in search engines etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look here: http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/34/asp-net-mvc-and-clean-seo-friendly-urls

There is a very long description how to do it. And the last part tells you about 301-redirects, which you should use to instruct search engine crawlers that the page can be found under the desired URL you wish.

Don't forget to take a look at the url-encoding, should save you some work and provide higher quality urls.

Here are some essential snippets from the blog post:

Set up your routing:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    "ViewProduct", 
    "products/{id}/{productName}", 
    new { controller = "Product", action = "Detail", id = "", productName = "" } 
);
```

Add the name-part to your controller and check that it is the right name:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id, string productName) 
{ 
    Product product = IProductRepository.Fetch(id); 

    string realTitle = product.Title; // Add encoding here

    if (realTitle != urlTitle) 
    { 
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"; 
        Response.StatusCode = 301; 
        Response.AddHeader("Location", "/Products/" + product.Id + "/" + realTitle); // Or use the UrlHelper here
        Response.End(); 
    }

    return View(product); 
}
```

**update**
The url apparently is broken. This article describes mostly the same functionality: http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/SEO-Friendly-Routes-with-ASPnet-MVC.aspx

Thanks to Stu1986C for the comment / new link!

Comment: Thanks. BTW, it's always a good habit to copy the critical part of the linked content to your post, so if tomorrow that link is dead, users can still benefit your answer. Also it will be more accessible and the answer will be more visible to people.

Comment: The link is dead. Here is the new one:http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/SEO-Friendly-Routes-with-ASPnet-MVC.aspx

Comment: Added the new link to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Both links are dead as of today 

Comment: Not too surprising it's gone after so long. The essential bits of code are in the answer anyway.